# how to delete every record except one per hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with millions of sensor records with the following structure:

```
datanumber (auto increment), 
stationid (int), 
sensortype (int),
measuredate (datetime),
data (medtext)
```

each stations adds a record every 2-10 minute per sensortype (2-5 sensors)

I would like to keep only one record per hour, per sensor, per station
and this too only if measuredate is older than 1 year.

I understand how to select data older than one year but I have no clue on how to delete rows except one for each hour. It does not really matter if it's the first, last or a random value which is kept at each hour. I also do not need to calculate average values or something, just strip down the amount of records stored

Comment: It sounds like you need a cron job. Have you looked into how it works?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like

```
Select * from observations where <old> group by sensortype, stationid, extract(year_month, measure_date), extract(day_hour, measure_date);
```

`group_by` will collapse the records in each group into one. You could select this into a new table if you want.

If you need to actually delete all the redundant old records, just select the datanumbers using the above query, and then delete all records `NOT IN(<those ids>)`.

Comment: I think you have to assume that roadfox does want to delete "redundant old" records, since that's precisely what he said he wanted to do.  Moreover, he doesn't want to delete any records less than or equal to one year old, which is not accounted for by the proposed query above.  In any case, it sounds like there will be many thousands, perhaps millions, of rows retained, so I am inclined to doubt that a `NOT IN` + subquery would perform adequately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be deleting a very large number of rows, then one approach recommended by the MySQL docs is to select the rows you want to retain into a temporary table, and then perform an atomic table renaming.  Maybe like this:

```
INSERT INTO
    sensordata_squeezed

  SELECT
      datanumber,
      stationid,
      sensortype,
      measuredate,
      data
    FROM
        sensordata
    WHERE
        measuredate < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    GROUP BY
        DATE_ADD(DATE(measuredate), INTERVAL HOUR(measuredate) HOUR),
        stationid,
        sensortype

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
      datanumber,
      stationid,
      sensortype,
      measuredate,
      data
    FROM
        sensordata
    WHERE
        measuredate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
;

RENAME TABLE 
    sensordata TO sensordata_old,
    sensordata_squeezed TO sensordata
;

DROP TABLE sensordata_old
;
```

Note well: that relies on MySQL's documented behavior with respect to selecting columns from an aggregate query that are neither grouping columns nor aggregate functions of the groups: it chooses an indeterminate value from each group.  (This is an extension to standard SQL.)  I am supposing that within each group, all the nonaggregated column values will come from the same row; you should check because that part is **not** documented, and this approach depends on that to maintain data integrity.

This approach allows you to avoid both large, expensive joins, and large numbers of subqueries.

Do note that however you do this, you are going to have to work around issues of how to avoid losing data that comes in while this operation is running, as it is likely to take a long time.

Comment: i try to run this on my db, but it blocks it for over an hour now already. so while it's not a problem to not accept new data during renaming of the table. i have to see if i can improve the perfomrance while the query is running

Comment: looks really promising, first i thought it blocks the db, but that was because i testet the query in phpmyadmin which is loked for hours then, if i run it on commandline all the other querys are still responsive. but cutover time to run the query and rename it will at least on first run be a problem. many thanks for pointing the direction

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lead-pipe cinch if we could use `row_number over( ... )` but a solution for MySQL is not difficult. For problems like this, look to see if we can query a list of just the rows we want to delete. That sounds easy enough. First, we want to have a list of each hour of each day and the first (least) entry for that hour:

```
select  Date( MeasureDate ) TheDate, Hour( MeasureDate ) TheHour, Min( MeasureDate ) MinTime
from    T
group by TheDate, TheHour;
```

So we just have to join the table back to this result set:

```
select  T.*
from    T
join(
  select  Date( MeasureDate ) TheDate, Hour( MeasureDate ) TheHour, Min( MeasureDate ) MinTime
  from    T
  group by TheDate, TheHour
) as T1
  on  T1.MinTime = T.MeasureDate
```

This gives us all the rows we want to *keep*. So use a `left join` to invert the results:

```
select  T.*
from    T
left join(
  select  Date( MeasureDate ) TheDate, Hour( MeasureDate ) TheHour, Min( MeasureDate ) MinTime
  from    T
  group by TheDate, TheHour
) as T1
  on  T1.MinTime = T.MeasureDate
where T1.MinTime is null;
```

Change the `select` to `delete` et viola:

```
delete  TDel
from    T TDel
left join(
  select  Date( MeasureDate ) TheDate, Hour( MeasureDate ) TheHour, Min( MeasureDate ) MinTime
  from    T
  group by TheDate, TheHour
) as T1
on  T1.MinTime = TDel.MeasureDate
where T1.MinTime is null;
```

You can add other fields such as `SensorType` as appropriate to keep first entry of each hour per sensor or however you want to tune it. <kbd>[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c9c1/4/0)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response and thanks for those explanations, this is a start and i have to fiddle some more to get a decent performance as at the moment it blocks the db for minutes. But i have now a clue how it could be done, many thanks!