# MySQL query to delete all the data except one with max time per hour

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have opensips deployed in production environment and more than one thousand users are registered with the it and every SIP Phone refresh its registration after 1 min. I have written a trigger which inserts a row in location_history table for every registration of the soft phone. Table registration_history is keeping the registration record of every sip user. The description of location history is:

id            int(10) unsigned
username      char(64)
domain        char(64)
contact       char(255)
received      char(128)
path          char(255)
expires       datetime
q             float(10,2)
callid        char(255)
cseq          int(11)
last_modified datetime
flags         int(11)
cflags        char(255)
user_agent    char(255)
socket        char(64)
methods       int(11)
sip_instance  char(255)
attr          char(255)

Now I want to keep only one record with max expire time in an hour in registration_history and want to delete the rest. Please guide me how to do this.
I have followed the query proposed by @tommcatt in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536658/how-to-delete-every-record-except-one-per-hour) thread but still there are multiple records of an hour in the database. my query is:

```
DELETE  ENTRY FROM location_history ENTRY
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT  username, Date( expires ) TheDate, Hour( expires ) TheHour, Max( expires ) MaxTime
  FROM    location_history  WHERE expires BETWEEN '2016-03-26 00:00:00' and '2016-03-27 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY  username, TheDate, TheHour
) AS T1
  ON  T1.MaxTime = ENTRY.expires
  WHERE T1.MaxTime is null AND ENTRY.expires BETWEEN '2016-03-26 00:00:00' and '2016-03-27 00:00:00'
```

This Query executes in a cron everyday but not working as per my requirement. After execution there are still multiple records in an hour.

Comment: `Mysql` <> `SQL Server`. Choose the one you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you mean one entry *per username*.  If so, you need to include that in the `on` clause:

```
DELETE lh
    FROM location_history lh LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT username, Date(expires) as TheDate,
                 Hour(expires) as TheHour, Max(expires) as MaxTime
          FROM location_history
          WHERE expires BETWEEN '2016-03-26' and '2016-03-27'
          GROUP BY username, TheDate, TheHour
         ) lh2
         ON lh2.MaxTime = lh.expires AND lh2.username = lh.username
     WHERE lh2.MaxTime is null AND
           lh.expires BETWEEN '2016-03-26' and '2016-03-27';
```

EDIT:

If you want only one record per hour, then remove `username` from the subquery:

```
DELETE lh
    FROM location_history lh LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT Date(expires) as TheDate,
                 Hour(expires) as TheHour, Max(expires) as MaxTime
          FROM location_history
          WHERE expires BETWEEN '2016-03-26' and '2016-03-27'
          GROUP BY TheDate, TheHour
         ) lh2
         ON lh2.MaxTime = lh.expires
     WHERE lh2.MaxTime is null AND
           lh.expires BETWEEN '2016-03-26' and '2016-03-27';
```

Comment: Yes right I need one record per username per hour. Let me apply first one.

Comment: The Query worked thanks, but if there are two records with same max(expires) value then this query keeps both of them.